# Google Nearby API on iOS background scanning

Tags: ios, swift, google-nearby

I've got the Nearby API set up in my Swift app and I can receive messages when the app is in the foreground. Following the [instructions in the docs](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/ios/get-beacon-messages#background_scanning)
 I try to include `params.allowInBackground = true` in the appropriate place but I get an error:

```
Value of type 'GNSBeaconStrategyParams' has no member 'allowInBackground'
```

So, I can't do that and my GNSSubscription object looks like this:

```
    subscription = messageManager.subscriptionWithMessageFoundHandler(
        messageFoundHandler, messageLostHandler: messageLostHandler,
        paramsBlock: { (params: GNSSubscriptionParams!) in
            params.deviceTypesToDiscover = .BLEBeacon
            params.permissionRequestHandler = { (permissionHandler: GNSPermissionHandler!) in
                // TODO: Show custom dialog here, and call permissionHandler after it is dismissed
                // show the dialogue
            }
            params.beaconStrategy = GNSBeaconStrategy(paramsBlock: { (params: GNSBeaconStrategyParams!) in
                    params.includeIBeacons = true
                    //params.allowInBackground = true //*** THIS DOESN'T WORK ***
                })
    })
```

My messageHandlers look like this:

```
    messageFoundHandler = {[unowned self](message: GNSMessage!) -> Void in
        print("Found handler:", message.type, "->", String(data: message.content!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        if UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState != .Active {
            let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
            localNotification.alertBody = "Message received" + String(data: message.content!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().presentLocalNotificationNow(localNotification)
        }
    }

    messageLostHandler = {(message: GNSMessage!) -> Void in
        print("Lost Handler:", message.type, "->", String(data: message.content, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    }
```

With this set up and an Eddystone beacon in range I now get notifications in the background! Since this is what I want I should be happy. However, if I leave the device connected to xcode with the app in the background I start to see a stream of messages like this (seems to be roughly every 5 seconds):

```
2016-07-23 19:35:08.243 Hoc[1269:622746] Can't endBackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 2f3, or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.
```

I'm using v0.10.0 of NearbyMessages. If anyone can point me in the right direction to get background scanning working reliably on iOS that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused by an issue with Cocoapods. Even though I used `$ pod update` and similar approaches to remove/re-added the NearbyMessages cocoaPod from my project, for some reason I couldn't get the latest version (1.0.1) of the Nearby SDK installed. The solution was to manually download the spec from [Github](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs) and overwrite the files in `~/.cocoapods/repos/master`.

Then to make sure I had the latest version installed, I changed my podfile to include `pod 'NearbyMessages', '~> 1.0.1'` which worked.

Now I can set the appropriate params on the GNSBeaconStrategy object and background scanning for Eddystone beacons works in the background on iOS. :-)

I hope this helps.

Comment: James, what did you originally have in your Podfile?  If you have `pod 'NearbyMessages', '~> 0.10.0'`, you wouldn't get the latest CocoaPod with background support.  Just be aware that by using `pod 'NearbyMessages', '~> 1.0.1'`, you'll get bug fix updates to the 1.0 version, but you won't get version 1.1 when it comes out.

Comment: Thanks @DanWebb  I originally only had `pod 'NearbyMessages'` with no version number. I'll change it to get the updates but something weird is going on with my cocoapod/git setup so I might not get them anyway. Thanks